# Not able to click dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am a new learner in selenium and try to click on a dropdown to populate list but it keeps on giving me runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
>     Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with )

Please help. Below is my code that I am executing.

```
    WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
    dr.get("https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/");
    dr.manage().window().maximize();
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    dr.switchTo().frame(dr.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("speed-       menu"))).click();
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to click on the webpage? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the Dropdown `Select a speed`, here is your own code with minimal changes:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
    dr.get("https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/");
    dr.manage().window().maximize();
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    dr.switchTo().frame(dr.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='speed-button']/span[@class='ui-selectmenu-text']")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/");
WebElement DynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("DynamicElement")));
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("yourid")));
```